# Instagram API Comment Endpoint only showing own comments on the post

Tags: api, instagram

I'm currently experimenting with the Instagram API in a Sandbox application.

When requesting to view comments for my own media, I only get the comments that I have made on my media but don't get to see other people's comments on my media.

As explained in https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/

Does this feature not work on Sandbox?